# How do I use a for loop to target many div elements?

Tags: jquery, gsap

I need to target multiple div elements. They all need the same action. They basically need to scale up on hover and down.

How can I pass the variable from my loop into jquery and gsap?

```
for (var sca = 1; sca<=12; sca++) { 
  $( "#sc"+sca ).mouseover(function() {
    TweenLite.to("sc"+sca, .5, {css:{ scale:1.3 }, ease:Back.easeOut});
    $( "#sc"+sca ).css("z-index","100");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    TweenLite.to(sc1, .5, {css:{ scale:1 }, ease:Back.easeIn});
    $( "#sc"+sca ).css("z-index","1");
  });
}
```

Comment: give your html code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give all of the `div` elements the same class, then you can attach the same event handlers to all of them at the same time using that class selector, without having to loop. Something like this:

```
$('.myClass')
    .mouseover(function() {
        TweenLite.to(this, .5, { css: { scale: 1.3 }, ease: Back.easeOut });
        $(this).css("z-index", "100");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        TweenLite.to(this, .5, { css: { scale: 1 }, ease: Back.easeIn });
        $(this).css("z-index","1");
    });
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're using `TweenLite` when jQuery has animation built in?

Comment: As @rorymccrossan said, this may lead to redundancy code as jquery animation methods are included and efficients

Comment: Thanks Rory. In this case it is all I need.

Comment: I used tweenLite when I did flash so I'm used to it and it is used on other parts of the site.

Comment: For what it's worth, TweenLite is *much* more performant than jQuery's animation methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fooDiv').mouseover(function () {
            TweenLite.to(this, .5, { css: { scale: 1.3 }, ease: Back.easeOut });
            $(this).css("z-index", "100");
        })
        .mouseout(function () {
            TweenLite.to('sc1', .5, { css: { scale: 1 }, ease: Back.easeIn });
            $(this).css("z-index", "1");
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop, instead bind the event handler to all elements with an id beginning with "sc", then use the reference to the actual element inside the functions:

```
$('[id^="sc"]').mouseover(function() {
    TweenLite.to(this.id, .5, {css:{scale:1.3}, ease:Back.easeOut});
    $(this).css("z-index","100");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    TweenLite.to(this.id, .5, {css:{scale:1}, ease:Back.easeIn});
    $(this).css("z-index","1");
});
```

Or, as Rory suggested, use a class instead (the class selector would be slightly better performance).

If you absolutely *had* to use a loop (you don't, as demonstrated above) then you'd need to create a closure that holds the value of `sca` for that iteration:

```
for(var sca = 1; sca <= 12; sca++) {
    (function(sca) {
        $( "#sc"+sca).mouseover(function() {
            TweenLite.to("sc"+sca, .5, {css:{scale:1.3}, ease:Back.easeOut});
            $( "#sc"+sca ).css("z-index","100");
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            TweenLite.to("sc" + sca, .5, {css:{scale:1}, ease:Back.easeIn});
            $( "#sc"+sca ).css("z-index","1");
        });
    })(sca);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event handler to the first common ancestor as a delegation event. This is a performance concern if you have many div to put in your document (better attaching handler to each of those div).

As an example

```
// Delegated event
    $('#commonAncestorID')
        .on('mouseover','.divClass', function() {
            TweenLite.to(this, .5, { css: { scale: 1.3 }, ease: Back.easeOut });
            $(this).css("z-index", "100");
        })
        .on('mouseout','.divClass', function() {
            TweenLite.to(this, .5, { css: { scale: 1 }, ease: Back.easeIn });
            $(this).css("z-index","1");
        });
```

See documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Plus, any div that would be appended later by via js in this same container would also get the effect on mouseover/mouseout event !